# Query Laravel Relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 3 Model

**In Purchase Model**

```
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'date', 'description', 'active', 'supplier', 'total', 'paid', 'purchase_status', 'payment_status',
    ];

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Product::class);
    }

    public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Order::class);
    }
```

**In Order Model**

```
protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'quantity', 'unit_cost', 'discount', 'tax', 'sub_total'
    ];

    public function order_items()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\OrderItem::class);
    }
```

**In my OrderItem Model**

```
    protected $fillable = ['active', 'description', 'quantity', 'discount', 'unit_price'];

    public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Order::class);
    }
```

Is it possible to query `Order_Items` From `Purchases` trough `Orders` Relationship in Laravel?

Comment: Please write your models and relations

Comment: i have order_id in purchase and order_items @mohammadHosseini

Comment: Yes I see..but you need to define your relations in your Models in Laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, i found my answer...

**In Order Model**

i changed `belongsTo` to `hasMany`

```
   protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'quantity', 'unit_cost', 'discount', 'tax', 'sub_total'
    ];

    public function order_items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\OrderItem::class);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can write this relations in your models and write the query like this:

Purchase

```
public function order()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Order', 'order_id', 'id');
}
```

Order_Item

```
public function order()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Order', 'order_id', 'id');
}
```

Order

```
public function order_items()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\OrderItem', 'order_id', 'id');
}

public function purchases()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\purchase', 'order_id', 'id');
}
```

Now you can use this query:

```
$purchase = \App\Models\Purchase::first();
$order_items = $purchase->order->order_items;
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you've fixed the relationship Order -> OrderItem of `belongsTo` to `hasMany`. But the question was also about how to query through relationships so I'll just add up to this so it could be useful to other users here.

Now you could do

```
$order_items = $purchase->order->order_items
```

to get the order items of the purchase.

However you should consider that this would execute further queries to the DB. One for fetching the `order` and then another one for fetching the `order_items`. If you're looping through a list of purchases, this could escalate quickly and end up making too much DB queries and affect the performance of your application.

The solution is eager loading.

You could do either pre-fetch the order and items along with the purchase like this:

```
$purchase = Purchase::with('order.order_items')->find(1);
```

or if you've already fetched the purchase, then you could do:

```
$purchase->load('order.order_items');
```

Then when getting the order items in your code like this
`$purchase->order->order_items`, you have no additional queries to the DB.

Comment: thanks for add more detail. anyway do u know how to query eager relationship using `vuejs`.

Comment: `vuejs` is the front-end part of the app. Relationships eager loading is handled in the back-end logic (i.e. the Laravel code above). Once the backend eager-loads the data, it just has to pass it to the frontend layer for doing the visualisation logic with the loaded data.

Comment: query relationship work fine, but when i try query using `relationship eager it doesnt work`.

Comment: "it doesnt work" is not very helpful. Please be more specific. Does it throw an error?

Comment: Nope, have not used it. Glad you've solved your issue. You could give an upvote if you think my answer was useful.